# And another insect from SE Brazil Oct 2017

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image: Large black and red flying insect with long legs]

Photographed in the low areas of the Brazilian Atlantic Rainforest - Oct 2017 and about 2cm in length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm having a difficult time pin-pointing the species, however, I'm fairly certain this [true bug](http://eol.org/pages/2639124/overview) belongs to the genus *Zelurus*.

*Zelurus sp.*
[image]

*Zelurus sp.*
[image]

*Z. variegatus*
[image]

## Distribution

[image]
*Interactive version can be found [here](http://www.discoverlife.org/mp/20m?r=0.2&la=-15&lo=-54&kind=Zelurus).*

[image]
*[source](http://www.biologiasubterranea.com.br/workspace/uploads/artigos/zelurus-in-brazilian-caves.pdf)*

Answer (score 2):

Great answer from @Charles: I was still humming and hawing between a zelurus species and another of the zelus species such as the longpipe that has the distinct red colour. (I had to leave for a couple hours...)  Like him, I was having trouble finding one that looked really similar.  But I found one, labeled as the **[Zelurus Circumcintus](https://www.flickr.com/photos/trekman/3088922557/in/photolist-5GXx4t):**

[image]

However, further research revealed that this is a fairly undocumented species.  The only source I could find with pictures of a distinctly red one was Flickr, such as [this one](https://www.flickr.com/photos/brutamonte/26348780170):

[image]

I'm guessing it actually is the zelurus circumcintus, but I have yet to find any official sources that back me up.

Comment: Zelurus species will be fine guys - brillient